# Can web audio gain nodes control other gain nodes?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'd like to create hierarchical "channels" where the parents gain will limit the child's gain.

So for example, I'd like sounds played on the child to have `0.1` volume.

```
var child = context.createGain();
var parent = context.createGain();
parent.gain.value = 0.1;
child.gain.value = 1.0;
child.connect(parent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, audio gain is chained hierarchically as described.

> It multiplies the input audio signal by the (possibly time-varying)
>   gain attribute, copying the result to the output. By default, it will
>   take the input and pass it through to the output unchanged, which
>   represents a constant gain change of 1.
>
> As with other AudioParams, the gain parameter represents a mapping
>   from time (in the coordinate system of AudioContext.currentTime) to
>   floating-point value. Every PCM audio sample in the input is
>   multiplied by the gain parameter's value for the specific time
>   corresponding to that audio sample. This multiplied value represents
>   the PCM audio sample for the output.

from http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#GainNode

Here is a complete example.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();

var parentGain = context.createGain();
var childGain = context.createGain();

parentGain.gain.value = 0.1;
childGain.gain.value = 1.0;

childGain.connect(parentGain);
parentGain.connect(context.destination);

var bufferSize = 4096;
var pinkNoise = (function() {
    var b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6;
    b0 = b1 = b2 = b3 = b4 = b5 = b6 = 0.0;
    var node = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
    node.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
        var output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
            var white = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            b0 = 0.99886 * b0 + white * 0.0555179;
            b1 = 0.99332 * b1 + white * 0.0750759;
            b2 = 0.96900 * b2 + white * 0.1538520;
            b3 = 0.86650 * b3 + white * 0.3104856;
            b4 = 0.55000 * b4 + white * 0.5329522;
            b5 = -0.7616 * b5 - white * 0.0168980;
            output[i] = b0 + b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6 + white * 0.5362;
            output[i] *= 0.11; // (roughly) compensate for gain
            b6 = white * 0.115926;
        }
    }
    return node;
})();

pinkNoise.connect(childGain);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can chain gain nodes serially, as you describe.  Note that this isn't a "limiting" effect in your example - it's multiplicative.  (If parent.gain.value were 2, the end result would be a .2x gain.)

Comment: Damn, I have to rewrite half of my app now. I create oscillators dynamically, feed them through gains, then every 2-3 of those gains go through a grouping gain and finally all the grouping gains go to a single master gain. No wonder, that after 4-5 oscillators I get a massive overdrive on the speaker. Now I have to do a transformation every time I change the number of oscillators.

Comment: Well they don't normalize, so sure, if you're mixing multiple oscillators together you're going to want to drop the gain.  You can use a compressor to do this, too; you can also just drop the gain on all the oscillators to begin with.